# SOQL Query to lookup field dependency?

Tags: soql, force.com, custom-field, search

A change needs to be done to this attribute/field Global Account Flag_c. In order to do so, I want to lookup dependency of this field Global Account Flag_c in all the objects present in our Salesforce system. I'm new to salesforce, is there a way to query this information using SOQL? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can attempt to change the field's metadata, however, and if the change occurs successfully, there was no dependencies that couldn't be resolved. Otherwise, you'll get a list of elements that depend on that field.